# SQL/Pandas Join Table/DataFrame on Column that Contains Duplicates in one of the Tables/DataFrames

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, join

I'm working with Python 3.7 and SQL Server.
Out of curiosity, I would like to know how to do this with both SQL and Pandas, but I also welcome answers with only one of them.

I'm trying to get data from two tables/DataFrames, and I think the best approach will be to join them.

Table 1 is structured like the following:

```
     item_id  attr_id
0        1     a1_id
1        1     a2_id
2        2     a3_id
3        3     a2_id
4        3     a3_id
5        3     a4_id
```

Table 2 is structured like the following:

```
     ATTRIBUTE_ID   ATTRIBUTE_NAME
0        a1_id        a1_name
1        a2_id        a2_name
2        a3_id        a3_name
3        a4_id        a4_name
4        a5_id        a5_name
5        a6_id        a6_name
```

I am wanting an output that shows all of the attribute names associated with an item, so it should have three columns: 'item_id', 'attr_id', and 'attr_name'. It would look something like this:

```
    item_id  attr_id  attr_name
0        1    a1_id    a1_name
1        1    a2_id    a2_name
2        2    a3_id    a3_name
3        3    a2_id    a2_name
4        3    a3_id    a3_name
5        3    a4_id    a4_name
```

I want to join the two tables/DataFrames on the 'attr_id' and 'ATTRIBUTE_ID' columns. The primary challenge I'm having is that there are duplicate values in 'attr_id' of Table 1 whereas there are only unique values in 'ATTRIBUTE_ID' of Table 2. Is it possible to join on these columns so that the values from the 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME' column in Table 2 are duplicated where required and associated correctly with their respective attribute ids? Not sure if it matters, but I'll note that the values in 'attr_id' of Table 1 are only a subset of the values in 'ATTRIBUTE_ID' of Table 2.

Comment: The answers from Balaji Ambresh and from bbaird both helped to answer my question. Since they both only provide part of the answer to my question, I can't mark either of them individually as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pandas version involving an `inner join` where `table1` and `table2` are dataframes of the tables in your example.

```py
pd.merge(table1, table2, left_on='attr_id', right_on='ATTRIBUTE_ID')\
    .drop(columns='ATTRIBUTE_ID')\
    .rename(columns={'ATTRIBUTE_NAME': 'attr_name'})\
    .sort_values(by='item_id')\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
   item_id attr_id attr_name
0        1   a1_id   a1_name
1        1   a2_id   a2_name
2        2   a3_id   a3_name
3        3   a2_id   a2_name
4        3   a3_id   a3_name
5        3   a4_id   a4_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Join in the database server when possible, for sanity's sake.  You could theoretically save I/O by bringing back the attribute table and matching in Pandas but that only works in very basic cases.

This is a very simple join condition:

```
SELECT
  item.item_id
 ,item.attr_id
 ,attr.attribute_name
FROM
  item item
LEFT JOIN
  attribute attr
    ON attr.attribute_id = item.attr_id
```

Left join in this instance because without a data model or looking at the database I don't know if the correct foreign key relation is in place.